# Is it OK to use a figure of speech like "the sooner, the better" in formal writing?

Tags: idioms

Is it OK to use a figure of speech like "the sooner, the better" in formal writing? The actual text is "The higher the kinetic energy, the greater the run-out." I understand that I can put "is" and "will be" in there. But do I have to?

Comment: "the sooner, the better" is a set phrase but not a figure of speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to put in "is" and "will be", and in fact I think your version is cleaner.

> The higher the kinetic energy, the greater the run-out.

You could also use a completely different sentence:

> There is a positive correlation between kinetic energy and run-out.

The latter may be better, since you are writing in a formal setting.